# How to loop pagination API to get full data all page?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-sheets-api

I have problem to sovle is import data form API to Google Sheet
But when I try url API it just get 1 page per request. I don't know to loop page to get all pages result.
This is API code:

```
import requests

url = "urlsample"

payload={'version': '2.0',
'appId': '1234',
'businessId': '7532',
'accessToken': 'Dk4qVfiJmdg9QnowtDHoXTvFAsuQpbI',
'data': '{"page": 2 ,"icpp":50,"parentId":0,"status":"New"}'}
files=[

]

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

I wanna loop `"page": 2` until get all data pages in Pytho or Google Colab
Anyone can help me ##

Thank you,
Best regard

Comment: Search for loops in python and learn it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to loop through the range of pages and add the response to a list of responses. Use a format string to write the page number where you need it in your payload.

```
import requests

url, responses = "urlsample", []
for page in range(1, num_pages + 1):
    payload={'version': '2.0',
    'appId': '1234',
    'businessId': '7532',
    'accessToken': 'Dk4qVfiJmdg9QnowtDHoXTvFAsuQpbI',
    'data': '{"page": {} ,"icpp":50,"parentId":0,"status":"New"}'.format(page)}
    files=[

    ]

    responses += requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, files=files).text

    print(response.text)
```